# Como podria limitar la cantidad de un campo

Tags: html, python, django, mvc, django-templates

de acuerdo al stock que tengo pr ejemplo tengo en stock 3 carros y vendo uno, para la porxima venta se limitaria el campo de cantidad a dos y no se podria elejir mas ya que en stock solo quedarian 2....

```
def agregar_detalle(request, slug):
template = 'programa/nuevo_prod_programa.html'
programa = Programa.objects.get(id=slug)
form = DetalleForm()
slug = slug
detalle = Detalle.objects.filter(programa__id__exact=slug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DetalleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form.modificarQuerySet(request.POST["tipo"], request.POST["producto"])
    if form.is_valid():
        form = Detalle(programa=programa, 
            tipo = form.cleaned_data['tipo'],
            producto = form.cleaned_data['producto'],
            cant = form.cleaned_data['cant'],
        )
        form.save()
        request.session['msg'] = " "
        return redirect('programa:total', slug)
else:
    form = DetalleForm()

data = {
    'form':form ,
    'programa': programa,
    'totals':  detalle, 
}
return render(request, template, data)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de acuerdo a la imagen mi campo cantidad no tiene establecido un limite de acuerdo al producto elegido

de acruedo a mi modelo de Producto..

```
class Producto (models.Model):
    TIPO_ACTIVO = 0
    TIPO_INACTIVO = 1
    TIPO_CHOICES = {
         (TIPO_ACTIVO, 'Activo'),
         (TIPO_INACTIVO, 'Inactivo'),             
     }
    tipo  = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    fecha_expiracion = models.DateField(null=True, blank = True, default='12/12/2020')
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    estado = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = TIPO_CHOICES, null=True, default=TIPO_ACTIVO)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)


   donacion = models.ForeignKey(Donacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '{}/{}'.format(self.descripcion, self.tipo )
```

mi formulario seria:

```
class DetalleForm(forms.Form):



tipo = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tipo.objects.all(),empty_label="--Escoger tipo--",
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder':'Tipo', 'onChange':"getProducto(this.value)"}))
producto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.none(),empty_label="---Escoger un producto---",
     widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder':'Produtos'}))
cant = forms.IntegerField(required=True, label=u'Cantidad', min_value=1)
```

Comment: En cual modelo tienes el stock?.

Comment: habia olvidado agregar el modelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def clean_cant(self):
    cant = self.cleaned_data.get("cant")
    producto = self.cleaned_data.get("producto")
       if cant > producto.stock:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _('Asegurese que este valor sea menor o igual a : %(value)s '),
            params={'value': producto.stock}

            ) 
        self.fields['cant'] = forms.IntegerField(max_value=value, min_value=0)


    return cant
```

en mi Formulario le agregue los siguientes cambios y pude solucionar este inconveniente con el codigo proporcionado

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entendí quieres el que el formulario no te permita agregar mas que el stock

```
def agregar_detalle(request, slug):
    template = 'programa/nuevo_prod_programa.html'
    programa = Programa.objects.get(id=slug)

    max_stock = Producto.objects.get ....

    form = DetalleForm()
    slug = slug
    detalle = Detalle.objects.filter(programa__id__exact=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DetalleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.modificarQuerySet(request.POST["tipo"], request.POST["producto"])
        if form.is_valid():
            form = Detalle(programa=programa, 
                tipo = form.cleaned_data['tipo'],
                producto = form.cleaned_data['producto'],
                cant = form.cleaned_data['cant'],
            )
            form.save()
            request.session['msg'] = " "
            return redirect('programa:total', slug)
    else:
        form = DetalleForm(max_stock)

     data = {
        'form':form ,
        'programa': programa,
        'totals':  detalle, 
    }
    return render(request, template, data)
```

Esta pregunta ya fue resuelta en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470741/django-forms-integerfield-set-max-value-on-runtime)
Tendrás que modificar el `DetalleForm`

```
class DetalleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, max_stock, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetalleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cant'] = forms.IntegerField(max_value=max_stock)            ...
```

Comment: al realizar esta accion no logro mucho. por que programa.stock no esta en mi modelo stock esta en mi modelo producto

lo que consegui estrar aquella validacion de django con el max value colocandolo dentro de mi metodo que se encuentra en el  Form Detalle.. dejare mi respuesta con el inconveniente que tengo al realizar estos cambios